# How to get last file name in dir command?

Tags: batch-file

I have a log folder, with files in the following names:

`number.txt` 
(example: `1.txt 3.txt 55.txt ...`)

The name (number) not necessarily means the that it is latest date.

I want to write a batch script (`.bat`) which get the biggest file number and create a new text file with next number
 (if the biggest file number was X, I want to create a new text file with the name X+1)

for example:

Suppose we have those files in the log folder:

```
1.txt 
5.txt
99.txt
```

After running the script (.bat) a new file `100.txt` need to be created

How can I do it ?

Comment: How can I do it is not an appropriate question for StackOverFlow. You should be attempting to code a solution first and then ask a question about the code you are trying to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really support off topic questions, but this is really not rocket science:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set cnt=0
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
    set "num=%%~ni"
    if !num! GTR !cnt! set cnt=!num!
)
set /a newfile=cnt+1
type nul > %newfile%.txt
```

It is really straight forward. We set a counter of 0 (`cnt=0`).

Loop through all files and remove the extension by using only the name from the token (`%%~ni`), so we have only the number left ad assign it to a variable `num=%%~ni`.

Then we match the file number with the counter, `if` the file number is greater than the the counter, we `set` the counter number to that same value, until we looped to the highest number, then simply take that value +1 and create the file by `type nul > newnumber.txt`

See loads of help around the commands used by simply running `for /?`, `if /?`, `set /?` and `setlocal /?` from `cmd.exe` terminal window.

Answer (score 3):

*"How can I do it?"* is not a valid question here... However, **I** do it this way:

```
@echo off

for %%i in (*.txt) do set /A "i=%%~Ni-next+1,next+=((i>>31)+1)*i"
rem/>%next%.txt
```

Comment: Well, no one said you should let the OP's brains explode :D